# How to wait for a function to complete in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this function where I convert a users pickup and delivery adress to coordinates. After I convert the adresses to coordinates, I want to calculate the distance for them. I convert and calculate these by using REST apis.

These are the functions where I get the coordinates

```
        if let url = URL(string: "APIURL"){
        

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task  = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("Error converting adress to coordinates: \(err)")
            }
            
            if let safeData = data{
                
                self.parseJSON(with: safeData, adressType: "From")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    if let url = URL(string: "APIURL"){
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task  = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("Error converting adress to coordinates: \(err)")
            }
            
            if let safeData = data{
                
                self.parseJSON(with: safeData, adressType: "To")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

So what I want is for those two to complete. After I have gotten those values, I want to calculate the distances.

This is the distance request

```
        if let url = URL(string:"APIURL"){
        

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in

            if err != nil{
                print("Could not start task to fetch distance")
            }
            
            if let safeData = data{
                
                self.parseDistanceJSON(with: safeData)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Currently, they all reside in this one function

```
 func fetchDistance(fromAdress: String, toAdress: String){
          
         if let url = URL(string: "APIURL"){
                 // Fetch for fromAdress...
             }
           if let url = URL(string: "APIURL"){
                 // Fetch for toAdress...
             }

           if let url = URL(string: "APIURL"){
                 // Fetch for distance between fromAdress and toAdress...
             }
    }
```

The only problem is that I want them to execute in the exact order you see in the code. But right now, it isn't in my control. Sometimes the last fetch executes first, sometimes they execute at the same time.

Comment: Do the three functions depend on one another? That is, do you need something from the first call as input to the second? Or are they independent, that is, they can execute at the same time.  If the former then you invoke the second function in the completion closure of the first and so on.  If the latter, use a `DispatchGroup` to identify when all three functions are complete.  Note that you will need to supply a completion closure to `fetchDistance` since it can't `return` a value due to the asynchronous operations

Comment: you just build pyramid of doom, try working on GCD, that could be helpful for you.

Comment: You tagged this with SwiftUI. Generally if using SwiftUI, you’d use Combine which handles these dependencies well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third function depends on data from the first two, but the first two are independent.

You can use a `DispatchGroup` to execute the third function once the first two are complete.  It doesn't matter in which order the first two functions complete.

You do need to consider that one or more of the network operations may fail.

Since these network operations are asynchronous, you will need to pass a completion handler to `fetchDistance` and invoke it when the work is done.

Something like

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case locationNotFound
}

func fetchDistance(fromAdress: String, toAdress: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Double, Error>) -> Void) {

    var firstLocation: CLCoordinate2D?
    var secondLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var error: Error?

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter();

    self.fetchLocation(for: fromAddress) { result in
        switch result {
            case .failure(let operationError):
                operationError = operationError;
            case .success(let location):
                firstLocation = location
        }

        dispatchGroup.leave()

    }

    dispatchGroup.enter();

    self.fetchLocation(for: toAddress) { result in
        switch result {
            case .failure(let operationError):
                operationError = operationError;
            case .success(let location):
                secondLocation = location
        }

        dispatchGroup.leave()

    }

    dispatchGroup.notify() {
        guard error != nil else {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        guard let first = firstLocation, let second = secondLocation else {
            completion(.failure(MyError.locationNotFound)
            return
        }

        self.findDistance(from: first, to: second) { result in
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}

func fetchLocation(for address: string, completion: completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocationCoordinate2D, Error>) -> Void) {

    // Perform API call to get lat & Lon for address.
    // Convert lat & lon to CLLocationCoordinate2D
    // Invoke completion
    /// completion(.success(location))
}

func findDistance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D ,completion: completion: @escaping (Result<CLLocationCoordinate2D, Error>) -> Void) {

    // Perform API call to get distance as double
    // Invoke completion
    /// completion(.success(distance))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, Gonna try this solution now

Comment: It WORKED! The funny thing is my previous attempts were using DispatchGroup or completion handlers seperately, but didn't use them both. You always come through with the solutions. Thanks